# What is the meaning of an object of the class inside it's class-endclass definition?

Tags: oop, system-verilog, uvm

What is the meaning of the following code (2nd line) in which inside class uvm_resource_pool definition, instance (object) rp is created?

```
class uvm_resource_pool;

  static local uvm_resource_pool rp = get();

  // Function: get
  //
  // Returns the singleton handle to the resource pool

  static function uvm_resource_pool get();
    if(rp == null)
      rp = new();
    return rp;
  endfunction
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the *singleton pattern* gets coded in SystemVerilog. The singleton pattern is an OOP technique that makes sure only one instance of a class type is ever constructed. The constructor as well as the object `rp` are declared local. The only way to retrieve an instance of a object of the class type `uvm_resource_pool` is to call the static method `get()`, which constructs it the first time called, but then the next time it will just return `rp`. This is also how to solve the *static class initialization order fiasco*. You never reference a static variable directly, you always use a get() method that constructs it on the first reference.

Comment: Yes I understand the importance static method, which ensures only first time object will be created and then later on that same object will be reference.
But my question is how an object (uvm_resource_pool rp) can be created inside it's own class definition??

Comment: Means while compilation of rp, how compiler would know what uvm_resource_pool contains, because it has not yet completely compiled the class definition?

Comment: All the compiler needs to know is that `uvm_resource_pool` is a type when you declare `rp`, and it does know that because the compiler has already seen `class uvm_resource_pool`. This works just like a forward typedef would. Remember that `rp' is a class variable that will hold a reference to an object, it is not an  object in itself.